# for loop and array in PHP: add element only at last interation

Tags: php, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have an empty array ($report), and i want to create a multidimensional array with element of "$array"
The problem is that adds elements only for index = 2 (last interation). Why?

```
<?php
 $array= array("3,4","5,6","7,8");
 $report= array();
 for($i=0, $n= count($array); $i< $n; $i++){
      $lat= substr($array[$i],0,1);
      $lng= substr($array[$i],2,1);  
      $report= array(array($lat,$lng));
  }
  echo "<pre>";  print_r($report);

   ?>
```

Comment: You rewrite the array, to add item use `$report[]= array(array($lat,$lng));`

Comment: yeah so the problem it was only the method to add elements at array! If you write an answer i check it :) thanks a lot!

Comment: glad to help. I've written the answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line `$report= array(array($lat,$lng));` you reinit array every pass of the loop. To add new item to array rewrite it to

```
$report[]= array(array($lat,$lng));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the value of `$report` every iteration. Use this syntax to append to the array:

```
$report[] = array(array($lat,$lng));
```

The `[]` appends values to the end of an array.